# What's the difference between a Qt debug version and the Qt release version?

Tags: debugging, qt, version, release

In many cases, code which works in the debug version doesn't work normally in the release version. I always encounter these questions, just like the earthquake happening. Which Big Beer can help me to give some thought??

Comment: Debug versions are usually slower, larger, and take up more RAM. They have debugging symbols, which make debugging possible and simpler. Release versions are stripped of all non-production information.

Comment: Is this a question specific to Qt, or debug/release versions of *any* software?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally if an app works in debug but not in release it's because some variable or memory wasn't properly set to an initial value.

In debug builds variables and memory are generally set to zero but in release this step is skipped to save time. Extra data is also added around objects and allocated memory as barriers to detect memory overwrites.

Sometimes (very rarely) an optimization in release build introduces an error

Comment: So true! One could add that using valgrind can help to identify the origin of such issues.

Comment: @FFox So true! I carried a bug during 2 months (apparently harmless), and valgrind found that I was overflowing my pixel arrays due to a wrongly implemented round function.

Comment: @Martin Accidentally found a msg of yours in QT but tracker the other day. :)

Comment: @Karlphillip - and I still haven;t found a valgrind alternative that works on windows. Running a Qt app in Dr Memory produces warnings for every Qt call !