# QT runs but QImages don't display in release version

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, release

I have a QT application that works well in the debug version but not in release. The release version runs with no crashes or anything, but none of the QImages I use display. I'm pretty unsure what could be causing it.

I've seen this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829946/whats-the-difference-between-a-qt-debug-version-and-the-qt-release-version) and am currently checking for any values that aren't manually initialized.

However, in the mean time can anyone think of why QImages would display in a debug build but not a release build?

Note that I'm running both from QTCreator. I'm on Windows 7 using Creator 2.7.2 and QT 5.1.

I haven't supplied any code because I'm not sure what I would post given there are no issues in the debug build (but I can if it would make things clearer).

Comment: Where did you get your Qt Version? It sounds like you are missing image plugins for the release version. But I wonder how this could happen.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue. Indeed it was a matter of a variable not being manually set (that was being caught in debug and set automatically).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the issue was a variable that was automatically set in the debug build.

I needed to manually set it for the release version and now my QImages seem to be displaying just fine.

Comment: Could you tell a little bit more? you describe such a strange effect. I think this is of broader interest. Things like that are extremely hard do debug. So I like to hear stories like that. Helps me when I might get a similar problem.